# How to get the Stoock ROM from Huawei P30 lite New Edition (MAR-LX1B)?

Tags: root-access, adb

I am trying to root my new Huawei P30 lite New Edition(MAR-LX1B). I found out that there is no official version of TWRP for Huawei P30 lite New Edition(MAR-LX1B). After a long research I found out that there is [a way to root without TWRP](https://www.getdroidpro.com/huawei-p30-lite-new-edition-root-via-magisk/). But, you would need the stock ROM of Huawei P30 lite New Edition(MAR-LX1B).

I have long searched how to get the stock ROM, but could not find anything. So I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to get the stock ROM of Huawei P30 lite New Edition (MAR-LX1B)?

Comment: https://hcu-client.com/read-bootloader-code-huawei-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [site](https://huaweidl.com/download/p30-lite/mar-l21/10-0-0-276/) seems to have a link to the stock ROM. As with everything related to flashing and getting root access, do proper research as if things go wrong you might brick your phone. Also, note that I don't own your model, so can't ascertain if the file is legit or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found this website in advance, but I thought it was a scam because Malwareytes blocked the website and the website required you to enable notifications. However, when I investigated the website I was able to bypass the download blocking and was able to download a real version of Huawei Stock rom. However, now I have a new problem. Namely, to unlock the fastboot mode, you need a 16 digit code and the Huawei page to request an unlock code was turned off.)